# ZAP Proxy Not Working

Tags: zap, zapproxy

I am trying to Proxy my browser traffic through the ZAP Proxy tool. I have setup my browser proxy according to the user docs on ZAP site and the same as the instructions in the post below. My site I am trying to scan just hangs at the login page, but as soon as I disable the proxy everything works fine. Also, looking at the network traffic in the Firefox or Chrome Dev tools, it shows "Waiting for fonts.googleapis.com". Any ideas what I check or try? I have tried 4 different browsers

[Adding authentication in ZAP tool to attack a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516420/adding-authentication-in-zap-tool-to-attack-a-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out IIS and ZAP were both configured to use port 8080. I changed ZAP to use a different port and it worked fine.