# zaproxy - API scan with request header

Tags: zap

I want to use zap to scan a rest API endpoint which requires Authentication header.

To specify the header I have to right click the request in history tab and add header, however the request without header doesn't even get logged in history tab. How do I specify the request header?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding authentication in ZAP tool to attack a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516420/adding-authentication-in-zap-tool-to-attack-a-url)

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look at this blog post: https://zaproxy.blogspot.com/2017/06/scanning-apis-with-zap.html

Basically you can specify new headers via config parameters, eg:

```
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).description=auth1 \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).enabled=true \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).matchtype=REQ_HEADER \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).matchstr=Authorization \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).regex=false \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).replacement=123456789 \
  -config replacer.full_list\(1\).description=auth2 \
  -config replacer.full_list\(1\).enabled=true \
  -config replacer.full_list\(1\).matchtype=REQ_HEADER \
  -config replacer.full_list\(1\).matchstr=AnotherHeader \
  -config replacer.full_list\(1\).regex=false \
  -config replacer.full_list\(1\).replacement=abcdefghi
```

will cause the following headers to be added to every request ZAP makes:

```
  Authorization: 123456789
  AnotherHeader: abcdefghi
```

You can specify as many headers as you need to by using incrementing indexes.

Comment: Can you post the command you're using? Have you mounted the directory the config file is in as per https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Docker#zap-baseline-scan ?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my question occasionally. My error was not to use -z " " option

Comment: I cannot find a way how to set header parameters in the ZAP GUI. I tried to find in in History tab as it mentioned above in the question but without success. Could you advise how to set header parameters in GUI?

Comment: In the GUI you use Options / Replacer - see https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsReplacerReplacer for more details

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

[image: Open/Resend with Request Editor]

**Step 2:** Edit the request & replay the request.

[image: Edit the request]