# Testing Session Management with ZAP

Tags: security, zap

Is it possible to automatically test the session management with [ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project)?

This should be possible, because ZAP is referenced as a tool for testing session management in the [OWASP Testing Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Session_Management_Schema_(OTG-SESS-001)#Gray_Box_testing_and_example):

> **Tools**
>
> OWASP Zed Attack Proxy Project (ZAP) - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project - features a session token analysis mechanism.

But I can't find any documentation how to test session managment.

Note: There's a lot of documentation regarding [how to add authentication to ZAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516420/adding-authentication-in-zap-tool-to-attack-a-url/43272057#43272057) but not how to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several features included in ZAP related to testing session management.

You need the following AddOns (https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpUiDialogsManageaddons)

- Addon Active Scanner Rules (beta)
- Addon Passive scanner rules (alpha)
- Addon Passive scanner rules (beta)
- Addon Passive scanner rules (release)
- Addon Token generation and analysis
- Addon ViewState

These AddOns provide the following functionality...

**AddOn Active Scanners**

- Session Fixation
- Cookie Slack Detector (Reveal areas where session cookies are not actually enforced)

**AddOn Passive Scanners**

- Insecure JSF ViewState
- Viewstate Scanner
- Weak Authentication Method
- Cookie no httpOnly flag
- cookie without secure flag
- session id in url rewrite

**Addon Token generation and analysis**

Allows you to generate and analyze pseudo random tokens, such as those used for session handling or CSRF protection

**Addon ViewState**

ASP/JSF ViewState Decoder and Editor

**MainMenuBar > Tools > Encode/Decode/Hash...**

Could help to identify meaningful Tokens

---

The following Plugins are more related to authentication/authorization than session management but...

**AddOn SAML Extension**

Detect, Show, Edit, Fuzz SAML requests

**AddOn Access Control Testing**

Adds a set of tools for testing access control in web applications

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Are there some further documentations where these features are listed?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. There is the ZAP User Guide (https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help) and the Zap Wiki (https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/).
You can follow the methodology in the OWASP Testing Guide (https://www.owasp.org/images/1/19/OTGv4.pdf) "Testing for Session Management Schema" and using ZAP with its AddOns. 

For Example use the Addon "Token generation and analysis" for "Session ID Predictability and Randomness".