# Create ZAP context using ZAP-CLI

Tags: authentication, automation, command-line-interface, zap, zapproxy

I am planning to automate the entire ZAP scanning using [ZAP CLI](https://github.com/Grunny/zap-cli)

ZAP uses a context for form-based authentication. This context can easily be created manually using ZAP UI. But I need to automate this context creation so that any application with the form authentication can be scanned using automation.

Is there any way/workaround to do so?

[How to create ZAP context using ZAP UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61787082/8405123)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZAP-CLI is a 3rd party project and not supported by the ZAP Core Team. Right now we recommend using the Docker packaged scans, but we are also working on an Automation Framework which will be the recommended approach going forwards. Documentation on these (and all of the other officially supported options) can be found here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/